# React On State Change, Change style

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I'm having a really hard time and have been trying this for a week now Tried all sorts of things but couldn’t get it to work. I really can’t find anything on the Internet so please help me even though is might be a specific question

What I want to achieve:
I want to “compensate” the empty line of text1 or text2 with a Pending. Those lines are sometimes empty sometimes there is text. They change on an upload in a different component.
So if text1 is empty I want to add 1 to this.state.count

Why Am I doing this I want to Print a manual and the formatting is really important. There is Usually More Code Around But I removed it to make it essayer to understand

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class BspComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  karte: [],
  text1: "",
  text2: "",
  count: 0,
};
}

componentDidMount() {

axios
  .get("http://test.com")
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      karte: response.data,
      text1: response.data.z1,
      text2: response.data.z2,
    });
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}


render() {
return (
  <div>
   <div
      className="atDistance" /** This Componant should get a padding is text1 is empty */
      style={{
        paddingTop: `${this.state.count}cm`,
      }}
    >
      BLA BLA
    </div>
    <div className="wrapper" /** text1 and 2 change on an Upload in a difrent Component */>
      <p>{this.state.text1}</p>  
      <p>{this.state.text2}</p>
    </div>
    <div
      className="atDistance" /** This Componant should get a padding is text1 is empty */
      style={{
        paddingTop: `${this.state.count}cm`,
      }}
    >
      BLA BLA
    </div>
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default BspComponent;
```

What I Tried:

1. check in the render -> didn’t work bc I can’t reach state + have the Padding Component before the render of the states
2. check in ComponentDidMount ->didn't work no Idea why
3. with an onChange -> couldn’t call the function got an error bc I got in an endless loop

Would Be super cool if you have a good Idea how to handle this. I'm not getting anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just worried about having a padding then you do something like.

```
paddingTop: `${this.state.text ? 1 : 0 }cm`,
```

And apply it to your element.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class BspComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  karte: [],
  text1: "",
  text2: "",
  count: 0,
};
}

componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get("http://test.com")
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      karte: response.data,
      text1: response.data.z1,
      text2: response.data.z2,
    });
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}


render() {
return (
  <div>
   <div
      className="atDistance" /** This Componant should get a padding is text1 is empty */
      style={{
        paddingTop: `${this.state.text ? 1 : 0 }cm`,
      }}
    >
      BLA BLA
    </div>
    <div className="wrapper" /** text1 and 2 change on an Upload in a difrent Component */>
      <p>{this.state.text1}</p>  
      <p>{this.state.text2}</p>
    </div>
    <div
      className="atDistance" /** This Componant should get a padding is text1 is empty */
      style={{
        paddingTop: `${this.state.text ? 1 : 0 }cm`,
      }}
    >
      BLA BLA
    </div>
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default BspComponent;
```

If you want to increase count by 1 if you receive empty text then you can do this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class BspComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  karte: [],
  text1: "",
  text2: "",
  count: 0,
};
}

componentDidMount() {
const { count } = this.state;
axios
  .get("http://test.com")
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      karte: response.data,
      text1: response.data.z1,
      text2: response.data.z2,
      count: response.data.z1 ? count + 1 : count;
    });
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}


render() {
return (
  <div>
   <div
      className="atDistance" /** This Componant should get a padding is text1 is empty */
      style={{
        paddingTop: `${this.state.count}cm`,
      }}
    >
      BLA BLA
    </div>
    <div className="wrapper" /** text1 and 2 change on an Upload in a difrent Component */>
      <p>{this.state.text1}</p>  
      <p>{this.state.text2}</p>
    </div>
    <div
      className="atDistance" /** This Componant should get a padding is text1 is empty */
      style={{
        paddingTop: `${this.state.count}cm`,
      }}
    >
      BLA BLA
    </div>
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default BspComponent;
```

Let me know if you want something else.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It’s a nice solution but I have multiple lines (about 16) to check (text1, text2, …). For each empty line want to add 1 to the Counter and then take the Counter as Padding.